# MongoDB - find all search string words in multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find all words in a search string across multiple fields.  For example:

If I were to search "**java coffee**" in this data:

```
 { _id: 1, name: "Java Hut", description: "Coffee and cakes" },
 { _id: 2, name: "Burger Buns", description: "Gourmet hamburgers" },
 { _id: 3, name: "Coffee Shop", description: "Just coffee" },
 { _id: 4, name: "Clothes Clothes Clothes", description: "Discount clothing" },
 { _id: 5, name: "Java Shopping", description: "Indonesian goods Hut" },
 { _id: 6, name: "Java Coffee", description: "goods Hut" },
 { _id: 7, name: "Coffee Shop", description: "Just coffee Java" }
```

I would like for it to search for each word individually in each field and return all documents that had each search word in any specified field.

I should get ids 1, 6 and 7 back as results because of these matches:

```
{ _id: 1, name: "**Java** Hut", description: "**Coffee** and cakes" },<br>
{ _id: 2, name: "Burger Buns", description: "Gourmet hamburgers" },<br>
{ _id: 3, name: "Coffee Shop", description: "Just coffee" },<br>
{ _id: 4, name: "Clothes Clothes Clothes", description: "Discount clothing" },<br>
{ _id: 5, name: "Java Shopping", description: "Indonesian goods Hut" },<br>
{ _id: 6, name: "**Java Coffee**", description: "goods Hut" },<br>
{ _id: 7, name: "Coffee Shop", description: "Just **coffee Java**" }
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this in an efficient way for Mongo to execute it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a [`text` index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#text-index) to your collection to enable text search over multiple fields. In this case:

```
db.test.createIndex({name: 'text', description: 'text'})
```

Then, to find docs that contain both "java" and "coffee" in either field, you can execute a [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#text-operator) query with both words quoted to require that both words be found. Quoting the words turn them into [phrases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases) which invokes logical AND behavior instead of OR.

```
db.test.find({$text: {$search: '"java" "coffee"'}})
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  It even works if one of the words is a partial, like 'jav' instead of 'java'.  Do you know if there is a way to make it work for multiple partial words?

Comment: I wouldn't expect partial words to work reliably with a text search as it uses word stemming, not partial matching.

Answer (score 1):

If the search string is a space-delimited string, $text operator performs a logical OR search on each term and returns documents that contains any of the terms.

```
 db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "java coffee" } } )
```

The query will return either coffee or java is present in any documents of that collection.

See [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) for details.